# SAS merging with no common variable

Tags: merge, dataset, sas

I need to merge two data sets that have no common variable, and only one variable apiece. One data set is about 200 lines of unique values and the other is 80,000 unique lines.  I have tried the common merges, but cannot get what I'm looking for.   The following is what I'm after:

Set a variables:  x   y

Set b variables:  1    2   3

Desired merged data sets result (2 columns):

x 1
x 2
x 3
y 1
y 2
y 3

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, it seems like you're trying to do a many to many merge. Try a proc sql cross join/cartesian product:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select
*
from have1, have2;
quit;
```