# Merging two data tables with no common column/keys

Tags: merge, sas

I found a similar Q [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072216/sas-merging-with-no-common-variable), but it is not quite the same.

I have two data tables with equal number of rows, but they have no common columns. I just want row 1 of first table to match row 1 of second table, and so on...
Adding reproducible code here makes no sense for me, I think this is self explanatory.

Comment: use recrod_num = _ N_ in both the tables and then merge on this variable

Comment: good idea, bur are there no quicker way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include a BY statement in your MERGE.

```
Data want;
Merge a b;
Run;
```

Information on various ways to combine SAS datasets can be found here
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/69852/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p15jvywi5avt3cn1bee8r6c33ux1.htm